# How can I change layout constraints depending on portrait/landscape programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I build all my objects and labels programmatically and have a function called `setupLayout()` which looks like this:

```
 private func setupLayout() {

//The Image that presents the Logo of the chosen cryptocurrency.
    view.addSubview(cryptoIconImage)
    cryptoIconImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cryptoIconImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    cryptoIconImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    cryptoIconImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    cryptoIconImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true


//The Label that presents the name of the chosen cryptocurrency.
    view.addSubview(cryptoLabel)
    cryptoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cryptoLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    cryptoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cryptoIconImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    cryptoLabel.font = customFont?.withSize(32)
}
```

This keeps the layout nice and centered and works well for portraits, and it also works in landscape to do the same. The problem is when in landscape, I don't want the elements centered anymore, I want to move some to the left side of the screen, and some to the right (I didn't show all the items in setup) any other answers to this question all seem to use storyboards, and I have found this method to use:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let orient = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    print(orient)

    switch orient {
    case .portrait:
        print("Portrait")
        break
    // Do something
    default:
        print("LandScape")
        // Do something else
        self.landscapeLayout()
        break
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how I should go about changing removing and adding new contsraints, so that it works smoothly when going back and forth. I thought about having a landscape layout function() like:

```
    private func landscapeLayout() {
    view.addSubview(cryptoIconImage)
    cryptoIconImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//Removing centerXAnchor
    cryptoIconImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = false
    cryptoIconImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    cryptoIconImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    cryptoIconImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
//Putting it to the left side
    cryptoIconImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true

}
```

But This gives me problems with stretching and such, and getting rid of the labels content as it adds them new. How should I go about have 2 seperate layouts between portrait and landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do something like this:

**Declare variable to hold constraints.**

```
var cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenPortrait : NSLayoutConstraint?
var cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenLandscape : NSLayoutConstraint?
```

**Define both contraints**

```
cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenPortrait = cryptoIconImage.centerX.constraint(equalTo: window.centerX)
cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenLandscape = cryptoIconImage.centerX.constraint(equalTo: window.centerX, constant: -20)
```

**Activate them accordingly**

```
If Landscape {
   cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenPortrait.isActive = false
   cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenLandscape.isActive = true
} else If Portrait {
   cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenPortrait.isActive = true
   cryptoIconImageCenterXWhenLandscape.isActive = false
}
```

Comment: also you need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false only once.

Comment: So I define these all in setupLayout, and for each constraint ie I will need CenterXWhenPortrait, LeftAnchorWhenPortrait, etc. and then only activate them in my landscape/portrait switch, which should activate automatically on load? (sorry if confusing)

Comment: Well in that case it makes sense to figure out what the screen orientation is when the screen loads (loadView/ viewWillAppear) and then find a way to store it.  You can refer to that variable while setting up the initial contraints. Hope Im making sense.